# How to Convert .xlsx file to json without using any external library in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, xlsx

Hi all I was wondering if it is possible to convert .xlsx file to JSON without using any external library in angular??

Comment: use https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

Comment: it is possible without any library?